# Ionic4 With vue, Google Maps working in browser, but not device

Tags: api, google-maps, vue.js, ionic4

**Hi All**,

I follow this tutorial to use ionic with vue: https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-the-ionic-vue-beta/

I have used API and call it in index.html in public folder. It works perfectly when I Npm run serve to test it in a browser. However, I use capacitor(ionic framework) to build android and Ios, I do npx cap add android to build apk to my android phone.

all app works perfectly but when go to map page didn't show anything, show only blank page

If anyone has any ideas ?, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by using the browser debugger feature.

When you start your app via the usb cable using something like `ionic cordova run android` you can then use the browser on the development computer to see the error logs remotely.

If you are using a windows pc follow this guide to do this using Chrome:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android#using-chrome-devtools

If you are on mac follow this guide to do with Safari:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios#using-safari-web-inspector

Comment: Thanks @rtpHarry, but thin answer won't solve my problem I already  use capacitor to generate apk for android

Comment: I wasn't trying to show you how to generate the apk. When you follow this guide it tells you how to connect the app to your laptop so you can press f12 on your laptop, see the normal chrome/safari developer tools, but it shows whats happening on your app, including any errors that are output to the console.

Comment: Okey I understand you, Thanks @rtpHarry